# jQuery submit additional form field

Tags: jquery

I'm currently working on an extended to-do list in php / mysql. The list will have several fields where tasks occur.

To add the tasks i using following code:

```
    <form class="add-new-task" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="new-task" placeholder="Add a new item..." />
    </form>
```

Then a script submits the form:

```
function add_task() {
    $('.add-new-task').submit(function(){
    var new_task = $('.add-new-task input[name=new-task]').val();

    if(new_task != ''){
    $.post('includes/add-task.php', { task: new_task }, function( data ) {
        $('.add-new-task input[name=new-task]').val('');
        $(data).appendTo('.task-list ul').hide().fadeIn();
                delete_task();
            });
    }
    return false; // Ensure that the form does not submit twice
    });
}
```

And just so you know it, here's the add-task.php

```
<?php 
    $task = strip_tags( $_POST['task'] );
    $date = date('Y-m-d'); // Today%u2019s date
    $time = date('H:i:s'); // Current time
    $user = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $field = "";

    require("connect.php");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO todo (user, field, task, date, time) VALUES ('$user', '$field', '$task', '$date', '$time')");



    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE task='$task' and date='$date' and time='$time'");

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ){
    $task_id = $row['id'];
    $task_name = $row['task'];
    }

    mysql_close();

    echo '<li><span>'.$task_name.'</span><img id="'.$task_id.'" class="delete-button" width="10px" src="images/close.svg" /></li>';
?>
```

Now, i want to add a input field to my form called "field" and i can handle that. Where my skills fails is to make the script that submits the form to add-task.php submit the "field" input too.

Hope somebody will help me with that

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should works

```
var field = $('.add-new-task input[name=field]').val();

$.post('includes/add-task.php', { task: new_task, field: field }, function( data ) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would personally do, is name the fields so they match up with what you want them to be in the PHP, and then serialize the form:

```
 <form class="add-new-task" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Add a new item..." />
     <input type="text" name="field" />
 </form>

  $.post('includes/add-task.php', $('form.add-new-task').serialize(), function( data ) {
```

Otherwise, you would need to just send over the data for the other field:

```
function add_task() {
    $('.add-new-task').submit(function(){
    var new_task = $('.add-new-task input[name=new-task]').val();
    var field= $('.add-new-task input[name=field]').val();
    if(new_task != ''){
    $.post('includes/add-task.php', { task: new_task, field: field }, function( data ) {
```